# Collision between 2 sprites worries

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

**I apologize for the broken english and hope you can understand me**

Hello I need your help because I stuck for several hours now and it's starting to drive me crazy. I need to miss something but not knowing what.

I am currently developing a game with Phaser 2.2 and I try to make a collision system.

The principle is simple green areas should not be accessible, and the wall

[The exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4flD.png)

Here is the complete code

```
var game = new Phaser.Game (512, 512, Phaser.CANVAS 'phaser-example', {preload: preload, create: create, update: update render: render});

preload function () {

     game.load.tilemap ('bar', 'assets / maps / bar.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON)
     game.load.image ('cafe_tiles', 'assets / tiles / cafe.png');
     game.load.image ('wall_tiles', 'assets / tiles / cafewall.png');
     game.load.atlas ('player', 'assets / sprites / tremel.png', 'assets / sprites / tremel.json');

}

var map;
var layer_wall;
var layer_sol;
var layer_couche_1;
var layer_couche_2;
var layer_couche_3;

var keys;
var sprite;
var marker;
var player;

function create () {

     game.physics.startSystem (Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
 
     map = game.add.tilemap ('bar');
    
     map.addTilesetImage ('bar', 'cafe_tiles');
     map.addTilesetImage ('cafewall', 'wall_tiles');
    
     layer_sol map.createLayer = ('ground');
     layer_wall map.createLayer = ('wall');
     layer_couche_1 map.createLayer = ('couche_1');
     layer_couche_2 map.createLayer = ('couche_2');
     layer_couche_3 map.createLayer = ('couche_3');
    
     map.setCollisionBetween (1, 1000, true, layer_wall)
     map.setCollisionBetween (1, 1000, true, layer_couche_1)
     map.setCollisionBetween (1, 1000, true, layer_couche_2)
     map.setCollisionBetween (1, 1000, true, layer_couche_3)
     layer_couche_1.debug = true;
     layer_couche_2.debug = true;
     layer_couche_3.debug = true;
     layer_wall.debug = true;
     layer_sol.resizeWorld ();
    
     player = game.add.sprite (200, 200, 'player', 'tremel1');
     player.animations.add ('walk_down' Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames ('tremel', 1, 4, '', 1), 30, true);
     player.animations.add ('walk_up' Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames ('tremel', 13, 16, '', 1), 30, true);
     player.animations.add ('walk_left' Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames ('tremel', 5, 8, '', 1), 30, true);
     player.animations.add ('walk_right' Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames ('tremel', 9, 12, '', 1), 30, true);
       
     game.physics.arcade.enable (player);
     player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

     game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys keys = ();
    
}

function update ()
{
  game.physics.arcade.collide (player, layer_couche_1)

  if (keys.left.isDown)
  {
    player.x - = 3;
    player.animations.play ('walk_left', 8, true);
  }
  else if (keys.right.isDown) {
    player.x + = 3;
    player.animations.play ('walk_right', 8, true);
  }
  else if (keys.up.isDown)
  {
    player.y - = 3;
    player.animations.play ('walk_up', 8, true);
  }
  else if (keys.down.isDown)
  {
    player.y + = 3;
    player.animations.play ('walk_down', 8, true);
  }
  else
  {
    player.animations.stop ()
  }
}
```

As I have seen many times on the net + on the Phaser doc to manage the collision must be reported collisions

```
 map.setCollisionBetween (1, 1000, true, layer_wall)
 map.setCollisionBetween (1, 1000, true, layer_couche_1)
 map.setCollisionBetween (1, 1000, true, layer_couche_2)
 map.setCollisionBetween (1, 1000, true, layer_couche_3)
```

Then add physical player

```
 game.physics.arcade.enable (player);
```

And finally normally just add this in the update () method

```
 game.physics.arcade.collide (player, layer_couche_1)
```

Except game.physics.arcade.collide (player, layer_couche_1) I always false references and I do not know pk?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

player.x is the sprite position, player.body.x is the arcade physics position so in your update method you need to update player.body.x instead of player.x